# Update some data in firebase and leave unchanged other ones in the same "parent"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app on android with firebase and I got stuck :(. I want to update some data in firebase and leave unchanged other ones in the same "parent". But when I use ref.updateChildren() function I am losing unchanged data :(. Like here:

Start data (before change) - The data that I don't want to change is marked blue
[image: Start data (before change) - The data that I don't want to change is marked blue]

Data when the editor activity is finished:
[image]

My code in EditorActivity :

```
[...]
            mEvent.setPlace(placeString);
            mEvent.setDate(dateString);
            mEvent.setType(mType);
            mEvent.setWindPower(wind_power);
            mEvent.setWaveSize(wave_size);
            mEvent.setConditions(mConditions);
            mEvent.setComment(commentString);

            Map<String, Object> eventValues = mEvent.toMap();
            Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
            childUpdates.put("/"+mEvent.getId(),eventValues);

            mEventsDatabaseReference.updateChildren(childUpdates); [...]
```

On the Event.class :

```
@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("id", mId);
    result.put("mUsername", mUsername);
    result.put("place", mPlace);
    result.put("date", mDate);
    result.put("windPower", mWindPower);
    result.put("waveSize", mWaveSize);
    result.put("type",mType);
    result.put("comment",mComment);
    result.put("conditions",mConditions);
    result.put("photoUrl",mPhotoUrl);
    return result;
}
```

I know that I don't have "mMembers" in "result " and "mEvent" but I want to leave them unchanged in firebase database like on updateChildrenAsync() function from ["Admin firebase"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend has sent me a code that solves my problem, it may be useful to someone in the future:
In EditorActivity:

```
            mEvent.setPlace(placeString);
            mEvent.setDate(dateString);
            mEvent.setType(mType);
            mEvent.setWindPower(wind_power);
            mEvent.setWaveSize(wave_size);
            mEvent.setConditions(mConditions);
            mEvent.setComment(commentString);

            Map<String, Object> eventValues = mEvent.toMap();
            mEventsDatabaseReference.child(mEvent.getId()).updateChildren(eventValues);
```